# Fill Grid with single column from linq Query

Tags: vb.net, linq, datagrid

I want to fill by datagrid with information I am getting from a linq query. The datagrid auto generates its columns

Using db As New DataClassesDataContext

```
        Dim fillGrid = From info In db.tableName
                       Select info.Description
        DataGrid1.DataSource = fillGrid
        DataGrid1.DataBind()
    End Using
```

This code generates a column called "Length"

If I add another column to select then it generates the columns properly since the list has --> Description = "" : ID =  ""

How can I get the linq to generate the column name with a single column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq to sql creates anonymous type when your select is not of a known type. In your case it is a list of string anonymous type. Binding on .net works only for properties and not for fields. So the default property for list of string is Length property which is used to.
Instead of this I would suggest you to create a class with a string property named description and do select as this class object:

```
Public Class StringCollection
    Private _Description As String
    Public Property Description() As String
        Get
            Return _Description
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Description = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Then do the selection:

```
 Dim fillGrid = From info In db.tableName
                           Select New StringCollection With {.Description = info.Pershkrimi}
```